# Не вызывается контекстное меню

Tags: java, android, android-context-menu

Элемент Listview не реагирует на длительное нажатие и не вызывается контекстное меню

```
    private final int CM_DELETE = 1;
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            boxAdapter = new BoxAdapter(products,this);
            ListView lvMain = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvMain);
            lvMain.setAdapter(boxAdapter);

            registerForContextMenu(lvMain);
        }


        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, 
        ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            menu.add(0,CM_DELETE,0,"Удалить элемент");
            super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            if (item.getItemId() == CM_DELETE) {
                AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
                products.remove(acmi.position);
                boxAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;

            }
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
```

Comment: для правки вопроса нажмите [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Попробуйте поменять местами строки в методе `onCreateContextMenu`

Comment: Поменял, не помогло